# Operator overloading (--) sets variables to 0

Tags: c++

When I call r--; My object resets the values to 0. Any ideas?

```
class MyClass : Superclass {
private:
    int length;
    int width;

public:
    MyClass() {
        length = 0;
        width = 0;
    }

    MyClass (int x, int y):Superclass(x/2,y/2){
        length = x;
        width = y;

    }

    MyClass operator--(int) {
        MyClass temp = *this;
        temp.length --;
        temp.width --;
        return temp;
    };
};
```

Creating and trying the class:

```
MyClass *r = new MyClass(2,3);
r--; // now length and width = 0 (should be 1,2)
```

Comment: As you've written it here, `r--` is decrementing a pointer, so `r` no longer points at the object you allocated. Trying to use or look at what it points at gives undefined behavior.

Comment: Your operator needs to modify `this->length` and `this->width`, not those on the copy. The postfix operator should modify `this` and return a copy of the object's state prior, so you need to replace `temp.length --;` with `length --;` and ditto for `width`.

Comment: BTW: You should implement `MyClass::operator--(int)` with `MyClass::operator--()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, the operator doesn't decrement the object it's called on, but the copy it's going to return. It should leave that alone (to return the previous value) and decrement the object:

```
MyClass temp = *this;
this->length--;   // this-> is optional
this->width--;
return temp;
```

Secondly, `r` is a pointer. `r--` decrements the pointer, not the object it points to, leaving it pointing to an invalid memory location. Dereferencing it afterwards gives undefined behaviour.

I've no idea why you're using `new` here; you almost certainly just want a variable:

```
MyClass r(2,3);
r--;   // should behave as expected.
```

If you really do want a pointer for some reason, you'll have to dereference it to get the object:

```
(*r)--;
```

and don't forget to delete the object once you've finished with it. And not before.

Comment: It still won't work, because `operator--(int)` modifies `temp` not `*this`

Comment: Just learning c++ so not sure about overloading yet... Is there a better way to write it?